# Make Android Screen never dim while on a particular activity?

Tags: android

Going through logs from 2009, it seems that everyone was complaining that this wasn't an option.

Now all I'm finding is people telling people different ways to do it, none of which work on my device. keepScreenOn, or its corresponding flag in LayoutParams, only serves to keep the screen on, even though multiple people have offered it as a solution for screen dimming.

WakeLocks, on the other hand (as I have seen them demonstrated online, anyway), appear to do absolutely nothing, not even keep the screen alive. The screen dims at the normal time, and I even get to see this hilarious little number on the monitor I have running on my laptop:

```
02-04 00:10:30.687: D/PowerManagerService(192): @PowerManagement: 'MyActivitiyName' releaseWakeLock when screen locked
```

I made sure to follow all the wakelock instructions on this page: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-keep-screen-onawake-3-possible-ways/

There were no build errors, and no runtime errors, either. The screen just dims and then shuts off, in the standard time frame.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was being dumb about the flags, following tutorials too blindly. I assumed the example wakelock flag was supposed to make the screen not dim, but it was the opposite. I switched the wakelock flag to

```
PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
```

and moved the wakelock acquire and release to onCreate and onDestroy, and now it does what I want.

(to be clear, this does what I want because the current activity is the final state I need for my demo; onDestroy should be called whenever I would possibly want to pause the activity)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this statement in the onCreate() method:

```java
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: It doesn't, sorry. I've tried that too, and it does the exact same thing as the XML solution that uses the same flag.